# How to display the result of a function in a label that returns list items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to write a program that first reads email addresses from a csv file and then draws 5 of them. I would like it to display in a desktop application. I don't know how to display the function result in the label field after pressing the button.

```html
import csv
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
 
with open('test.csv') as csv_plik:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_plik, delimiter=',')
 
    numbers = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        number = row[0]
        numbers.append(number)
 
lenght = len(numbers)
 
def losowanie():
    i = 0
    z = 1
    while i < 5:
        lenght = len(numbers)
        y = lenght
        c = random.randint(0, y - z)
        print(numbers[c])
        numbers.remove(numbers[c])
        i+=1
 
main = tk.Tk()
main.geometry('400x400')
w = tk.Button(main, text = 'Losuj', command = main.destroy)
w.place(x=180, y=180)
 
y = tk.Label(main, text='losowanie')
y.pack()
y.place(x = 180, y = 220)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: first you have to assign to button function - not `main.destroy`. To change text in label `y` - `y['text'] = "Nowy tekst"`

Comment: if you use `place()` then don't use `pack()` (or `grid()`) - `place` and `pack` are two different methods to organize widgets in window/frame - there is no sense to use both.

Comment: to get 5 random items you can shuffle list - `random.shuffle(numbers)` - and you will have items in random order and then you can get first 5 items - `result = numbers[:5]`. Or you can use `result = random.choices(numbers, 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 5 random values from list you can use

```
values = random.choices(numbers, k=5)
```

next you have to convert list to one string

```
new_text = ','.join(values)
```

and finally you can replace text in label

```
label['text'] = new_text
```

And you have to assign function to button

```
command=losowanie
```

---

```
import csv
import random
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def losowanie():
    values = random.choices(numbers, k=5)
    new_text = ','.join(values)
    label['text'] = new_text

# --- main ---

with open('test.csv') as csv_plik:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_plik, delimiter=',')

    numbers = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        number = row[0]
        numbers.append(number)


main = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(main, text='Losuj', command=losowanie)
button.pack()

label = tk.Label(main, text='losowanie')
label.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: BTW: examples for tkinter and other modules in Python I keep on GitHub (PL: przykłady dla tkinter i innych modułów w Pythonie trzymam na GitHub) [furas/python-examples/tkinter](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter)